# How to change toolbar's title as we scroll down a recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What I want to achieve is change the toolbar title to the new month my recyclerview data belongs to à la google calendar. For example, "January" will be the toolbar's title when the first data of January is scrolled in view or to the top (I haven't decided on this yet). To accomplish this I've been thinking to pass my toolbar to my recyclerview adapter and change the toolbar title as the user scrolls down the list as my data is well structured and contains both headers and data.

My JSON Data:

```
[ {
    "m" : 6,
    "name" : "June 2018",
    "y" : 2018
  }, {
    "category" : 0,
    "created_at" : 1528101463478,
    "date" : 1528416000000,
    "movie" : 12132,
    "human" : "2018-Jun-08",
    "id" : 153351,
    "m" : 6,
    "platform" : [ 14, 6 ],
    "region" : 8,
    "updated_at" : 1528101564611,
    "y" : 2018
  }, {...}]
```

And my adapter looks like this, I don't yet know where to place my code to change the toolbar on scroll and if it's better to place it outside the adapter completely.

```
public class UpcomingsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReleaseHolder>  {
    public static final String TAG = UpcomingAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
    public final static int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    public final static int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context mContext;
    // Data
    private List<_Release> data;

    public UpcomingAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    public void setData(List<_Release> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ReleaseHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ReleaseHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.release_item, parent));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ReleaseHolder holder, int position) {
        // holder.setDetails();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
}
```

List data in the adapter will contain both header items and release items.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [**`RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#addonscrolllistener)

> Add a listener that will be notified of any changes in scroll state or position.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            int itemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(arrayList.get(itemPosition));

        }
    });
```